# Brightness not working Acer Aspire One 756-2623

Tags: 12.04, laptop, acer, backlight, aspire-one

Brightness not working Acer Aspire One 756-2623 with Ubuntu 12.04. Also the mousepad right-click isn't working ether. I'm completely new to Ubuntu and Linux in general.

How do I fix it?